# How to get date string from this?

Tags: c#, string, parsing

```
string tmp = "Monday; 12/11/2013 | 0.23.59
```

How would I get date string , that is 12/11/2013. I have try this:

```
int sep=tmp.IndexOf(";");
int lat=tmp.IndexOf("|");
string thu = tmp.Substring(0, sep);
string tem = tmp.Substring(lat + 1);
string ngay = tmp.Substring(sep, tmp.Length - (sep+tem.Length);
Console.WriteLine("Date: {0}", ngay);
```

How can this be done in C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
string tmp = "Monday; 12/11/2013 | 0.23.59";
var dateString = tmp.Split(new [] { ';', '|' })[1].Trim();
```

[`String.Split()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) allows you to specify delimiter characters so you don't have to worry about getting positional offsets (e.g. +2, -1, etc.) correct.  It also allows you to remove empty entries, and (IMHO), is a little easier to read the intent of the code.

Comment: Thank you, but Error The best overloaded method match for 'string.Split(char[], System.StringSplitOptions)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: Try it the way it's written now. I was working from memory and often get the parameters incorrect. It's tested and working as you intend now.

Answer (score 4):

The algorithm you've worked out just needs a little adjustment if you want just the date part. Try this:

```
string tmp = "Monday; 12/11/2013 | 0.23.59";

int sep=tmp.IndexOf(";") + 2; // note the + 2
int lat=tmp.IndexOf("|") - 2; // note the - 2
string thu = tmp.Substring(0, sep);
string tem = tmp.Substring(lat + 1);
string ngay = tmp.Substring(sep, tmp.Length - (sep+tem.Length));
Console.WriteLine("Date: {0}", ngay);
```

It will now output

> Date: 12/11/2013

Comment: You have a new avatar.

Comment: @KenKin Heh, I updated it a while back when I finally got tired of the gravatar.

Answer (score 0):

```
string tmp = "Monday; 12/11/2013 | 0.23.59";
            string date = tmp.Split(' ')[1];
```